# How to photograph sparkly clothing in (at least somewhat) natural situations?

Tags: lighting, smartphone, clothing

I have been attempting to capture the sparkles of [a rhinestoned mesh tank top](https://shop.hausofcircuit.com/products/rhinestone-mesh-tank-top-round-neck-1) with great difficulty. My attempts have been in well-lit spaces both indoors and outdoors, using smartphone cameras.

This is related to, but distinct from, [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/52908/how-to-photograph-sparkly-objects) about photographing sparkly objects, because I'm interested in capturing photos in a relatively natural setting rather than a studio with full control of the background and lighting.

An ideal solution would be something that works

- in well-lit indoor or outdoor spaces
- using a smartphone camera
- without special equipment beyond the lighting available in a regular home, or the torch on a modern smartphone
- for still photos rather than video

but I understand that's asking for a lot(!) so I'm still interested in advice that drops one or more of those constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Either I answer your question or stick to your limitations and not answer at all.

So, let me explain using a small section of your image.

[image]

**What is a sparkle on a reflective material?**

It is a flare of an overexposed zone that is reflecting the full intensity of the light source.

- **A "flare"** is the effect of an intense enough light so some internal reflections or diffractions from the lens are captured.
- **of an overexposed zone** A light source is several magnitudes more intense than a pure matt white material. A flare looks bigger than the zone itself. The light is spilled out.
- **that is reflecting the full intensity of the light source** Meaning that the material is not white, but glossy or metallic, and the incident angle and the reflective angle are right so what you are seeing is a reflection of the light source.

---

So. I am pretty sure in your house or outdoors you have light sources. Checked.

**But does the angle of the reflection points this reflection to your camera lens?**

The probability **is very low**. At most, you will have only 1 or 2 of those little mirrors pointing somewhere near your camera. If you point a strong flashlight on a dark room you will see the room filled with small dots. One or two of those small dots need to point to your **tiny smartphone lens**.

---

**In order to augment the possibility of capturing the reflection of the light source, you can use a bigger light source. Lot bigger. Aka a softbox.**

Normally light sources, indoors and outdoors are point lights. Just one light bulb here and there, and the sun.

Even a small softbox let's say only 60x60cm, near the subject has several hundreds or thousand times more area than a point light. Increasing the possibility of seeing that reflection.

So, either you move a lot trying to capture one random reflection (probably having one assistant giving you instructions if he or she can see the reflection at all), or you get a bigger light source.

---

You can also try Star Filters, (or Starburst Filters, or Streak Filters) this can produce a flare with less intense light than normally needed for internal reflections.

You can simply smudge your lens and point to a light source to make a quick test.

---

Or add them in post.

Answer (score 0):

*Sparkles* are a **time varying phenomenon**. As the subject/light/angle changes, different portions gain and lose high intensity reflections toward the camera or eye, that is it *sparkles*. A single instant in time photograph will have bright spots, probably a very low percentage area wise, which could be referred to as *flares* but *sparkle* requires change. Look at a video of a sparkly outfit, then look at a single frame. No one frame sparkles.

For a still photo, I'd suggest a Star Filter to emphasize the low percentage flares and the smallest aperture you can manage to make the diffraction patterns as sharp as possible.